# Discrete time generator of stochastic process

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, discrete-time, generator

While looking at one [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoap/1034625254) about Metropolic Hasting optimal convergence rates, I came accross a discrete time generator of Markov chain. It is defined as follows:
$$G V(x)=nE\left [ \left( V(y)-V(x)\right )\left(1\wedge \frac{\pi(y)}{\pi(x)}\right ) \right ],$$

where $n$ is the dimension of $x$, $y$ is the proposed value by proposal distribution, expectation is taken w.r.t. the proposal distribution and $\pi$ is the target distribution.

My question is where could I find more information about the construction of discrete time generators? I know about the continuous time generators for diffusion processes, but cannot find information about the discrete analogue. 
A paper or (better) a textbook reference would be highly appreciated.